# CSS-PAGINA WEB- RESPOSIVE

Tags: html, css, web, responsive, after

como hago que la barra negra este justo en el centro cada vez que pase el raton se que es con after pero como la dejo en el centro y con el mismo tamaño. La verdad no encuentro en toda la web como hacerlo. Les dejo el css siguiente y una imagen muy clara donde se ve que al pasar el raton la barra queda a un lado y no en el centro como quisiera, en el codigo css el nav tiene la clase menu y el ul tiene la clase items__menu

adjunto imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
:before,
:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
  background-color: #33e0ff;
  color: #4a235a /*#f4f6f7*/;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #ffe333;
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.logo__menu {
  color: #4a235a;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.items__menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.items__menu li {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.items__menu li a {
  padding: 7px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #4a235a;
}

.items__menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
li:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 3px;
  width: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

Comment: Falta mucha información para poder ayudarte, favor leer el apartado "Como preguntar?". En estos casos es mejor pasar html y css para poder entender como tenés armado todo y hacer pruebas para ayudarte. Tampoco se entiende bien que es lo que deseas hacer, en esos caso es mejor quizás pasar alguna imagen de ejemplo y explicar el comportamiento que deseas.

Comment: solo quiero que la barra de la imagen quede en el centro al pasarle el mouse el codigo es css el que pase si ves a lo ultimo }
li:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 3px;
  width: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}  ahi aplico after para lograr esa barra negra pero quiero que este justo al centro y nada mas... como puedo alinearla eso es codigo css

Comment: Tal como te indicaron... si no pones el HTML también, cómo vamos a ayudarte? Que crees que nuestras cabezas generan el html a partir de la foto que adjuntaste?? Me temo que somos programadores, no ordenadores. Pon el HTML para que podamos probarlo y ver si podemos arreglarlo hombre! Puedes usar el enlace para [edit]

Comment: <nav class="menu">
<label class="logo__menu">THE SUNSHINE NEWS</label><ul class="items__menu">
<li class="activo__menu"><a  href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="div1"><div class="div2"></div></div>
<span class="btn__menu"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
</span>
</nav>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cc26e9b68f.js" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: la segunda parte del html: <script href="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Felices fiestas **!**
Según entiendo, simplemente mover la barra negra de `10px` al centro del `li`.

Es muy fácil entendiendo las posiciones de un elemento posicionado absolutamente con sus respectivas declaraciones: `bottom`, `left`, `margin` etc.

Lo que hice es mover al centro con `left:50%`, lo que significa que esté a la mitad del`li`. Pero siendo la barra negra de `10px` y cada `li` variable en su anchura, no quedaría perfectamente al centro sino, un poco demás.
Entonces la solución completá y correcta sería moviendo al centro con un márgen `left` de **50%** y restándole la mitad del ancho de la barra negra que sería: **5px**:

```
li:hover:after { 
 left: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

Puede parecer confuso o complicado el `calc()` pero es cuestión de práctica y lógica: simplemente calcula **50% - 5px**; (el - 5px equivale la mitad de la barra negra).

**EXTRA**. Adicionalmente agregué otro efecto de la barra negra y esta comentado en CSS.

```css
 

:before, :after {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
 outline: 0; 
} 

body { 
 margin: 0; 
 min-height: 555px;
 font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
 background-color: #33e0ff;
 color: #4a235a /*#f4f6f7*/;
}

.menu { 
 background-color: #ffe333; 
 position: relative; 
 height: 75px;
 width: 100vw;
 display: flex; 
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: 5px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.logo__menu { 
 color: #4a235a;
 font-size: 35px;
 padding: 0 80px;
 font-weight: bold;
} 

.items__menu {
 display: flex;
 list-style: none; 
 margin-right: 30px; 
 background: red
} 

.items__menu li {
 position:relative;
 border-radius: 3px; 
 margin: 0 5px;
} 

/* SOLUCIÓN */

.items__menu li:after {
 content: ''; 
 position: absolute; 
 background-color: #000; 
 height: 3px;
 width: 10px; 
 bottom: 0;
 left: 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover:after { 
 left: calc(50% - 5px);
}


/* OPCIÓN DOS  */
/*
.items__menu li:after {
 content: ''; 
 position: absolute; 
 background-color: #000; 
 height: 3px;
 width: 10px; 
 bottom: 0;
 left: calc(50% - 5px);
 margin: 0 auto;
 transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover:after { 
 left: 0;
 width: 100%; 
}
*/

.items__menu li a { 
 padding: 7px 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 display: block; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #4a235a;
} 

.items__menu li:hover { 
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Barra hover en menú</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">  
  
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <nav class="menu"> 
   
   <label class="logo__menu">THE SUNSHINE NEWS</label>
   
   <ul class="items__menu">

<li class="activo__menu">
 <a href="#">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="#">Entertainment</a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="#">Fashion</a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="#">Pictures</a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="#">Videos</a>
</li>
   </ul> 
   
   <div class="div1">

<div class="div2"></div>

   </div>
   
   <span class="btn__menu">
<i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i> 

   </span> 
  
  </nav>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```